# Trying to read a Windows 10 system disk that was part of a Raid 1 set with Ubuntu (18.04)

Tags: mount, hard-drive, windows-10, raid

A friend of mine toasted his Windows 10 laptop which contained 2 mirrored 128 GB SSD disks. I am trying to copy the data from one of the system disks (a half of the mirror set) to save loss of data.

I have an adapter that allows me to plug the SSD into one of my USB ports and access the disk.

After powering up the system, the DISK utility sees the disk (at `/dev/sdg`) and indicates that the disk is OK with a bad sector. When I start GPARTED, it also sees the disk indicating the file system and the Partition are both unallocated.
I also tried mounting the disk, after creating a folder called `/mnt/windrv` with `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdg /mnt/windrv -o "unmask=022"` and the error I got indicates that the drive does not have a valid NTFS.

Is there any way I can read this disk on my Ubuntu system or do I need to find a Windows 10 system (and will that even work??)

Comment: Just to add to the above, I got a Windows 10 system from someone and tried to read the disk with it. Similar issue, not happy with the MBR of the disk so it will not read the content but it does recognize the physical existence of the drive (MBR mismatch or ambiguous).

Comment: Ok, I now see that the disk is actually GPT. Will try to run testdisk under Linux to see if I can get the data off of the SSD

Answer (score 0):

After buying a program to try and recover files (which it did but not any I wanted), I determined the HD was trashed as the pointers on the disk were compromised. Nothing could be done to recover the data I needed.
No success but a determination was reached and confirmed.